# PyTorch optimizer returning ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to implement a python code using PyTorch and in the part where I try to execute it, I get an error.

```
# Initialize PyTorch optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([t_value, t_norm, t_energy], lr=0.01)

# Execute PyTorch
optimizer.zero_grad()
op_init_model()  
op_norm()
v, n, e = t_value.item(), t_norm.item(), t_energy.item()
print("Init:\t{:.8e} = {:.8e} / {:.8e}".format(e, v, n))

def closure():
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    energy = t_energy
    energy.backward()
    return energy

optimizer.step(closure)

v, n, e = t_value.item(), t_norm.item(), t_energy.item()
print("Result:\t{:.8e} = {:.8e} / {:.8e}".format(e, v, n))
```

I tried to create a wrapper function for the optimization step:

```
# Calculate energy
class EnergyFunction(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, t_value, t_norm):
        result = t_value / t_norm
        ctx.save_for_backward(t_value, t_norm)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        t_value, t_norm = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_value = grad_output / t_norm
        grad_norm = -grad_output * t_value / t_norm ** 2
        return grad_value, grad_norm
    
t_energy = EnergyFunction.apply(t_value, t_norm)
```

but returns the same issue

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)